# AllJoyn: Sending message to a single device instead of broadcasting to all devices

Tags: alljoyn

I have set up AllJoyn stack (14.12) in multiple Ubuntu systems and have started ConsumerService in all the Ubuntu systems. Now when I start the ProducerBasic client, in one of the systems, the notification reaches all the systems (expected behavior).

However, in case I wanted to send it to only 1 system, how is that doable?

The scenario I am attempting is - I need to send a device command (like say reboot device) and I don't want the other devices to receive it.

I checked the API for NotificationSender

```
NotificationSender::send(Notification const& notification, uint16_t ttl);
```

There does not seem to be any other method for sending the data.

Thanks and Regards
Amit M Mangalvedkar

Comment: Do you mean 15.09 or 14.12? There was no 14.09 release.

Comment: I meant 14.12, my apologies for getting the 2 mixed up. I am modifying the query. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to say, you are using a very old version of the AllJoyn library, I strongly advice you to switch a more updated version like (15.09 or 16.04)

Notification Service is a public service of AllJoyn, when you use it, it will broadcast messages to all the nearby peers.

In your case, you can create a private service (in other words, a BusObject attached to the AllJoyn Bus) and use event/action mechanism defined in AllJoyn. You can find more information at the docs. https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/api-guide/events-and-actions

Hope that helps.

Comment: Although I would have really liked using the later versions, the actual use case involves triggering the command from outside the proximal network. So that means I need to make use of the AllJoyn Gateway. However, the last stable gateway stack is still on 14.12. So I am kind of stuck on the older stack. Let me try the approach that you have suggested - creating private service.

Answer (score 0):

As Fatih said, the Notification Service will broadcast messages to all peers. You have the following options. Based on your need I don't think you want to use the Notification Service.

Since you want a "Reboot" command, you might consider supporting the Config Service on the node that needs to be rebooted. The [org.alljoyn.Config interface](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/learn/base-services/configuration/interface) has a "Restart" method that is for that purpose. It's not well-documented, but it's simple enough. And the [Android Java ConfigClient has a restart method](https://allseenalliance.org/docs/framework/java/config/org/alljoyn/config/client/ConfigClient.html#restart()) to call on a node that supports the Config Service.

To implement the Config Service you derive a class from the abstract ajn::services::ConfigService::Listener class (#include <alljoyn/config/ConfigService.h>) and implement the virtual functions.

Another alternative would be to create your own Reboot method on your own interface and implement that, though I would recommend using ConfigService since it is already there and enforces security.

Comment: Thanks John for the approaches. Let me try the approaches.